# how to import swf file has "DocumentMain.as" to another swf file?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I'm creating a game in flash CS5 actionScript3 with separate "DocumentMain.as" for the code and I want to import it to another swf file which is the menu. I want when I click start in menu it takes me to the game file!

Here is the code that I use

```
    btnstart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gamecontent);
function gamecontent(myevent:MouseEvent):void{
    var myURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("game.swf");
    myLoader.load(myURL);
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
    function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event):void
    {
        addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);

    }

}
```

However, it dose not work and it shows me this message
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at DocumentMain()"

Please I need your help!!!
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To find the problem it's easiest to try and add the full path to the game.swf in the URLRequest.. if it works then, then you know that all you have to do is changing it back to "game.swf", re-save the fla-file in the same folder as the game.swf, and export the preview swf to the same folder and try again.. That worked for me when I had the exact same problem.. it' just doesn't seem to know where it's root folder is.

```
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.display.Loader;

  btnstart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gamecontent);
  function gamecontent(myevent:MouseEvent):void{
  var myURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("file:///c:/yourfolder/folder/game.swf");
  myLoader.load(myURL);
  myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
  function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event):void
          {
           addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);            
          }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably accessing `stage` in the `DocumentMain` constructor.  This throws an error when loading a SWF into another because the stage is not available right away in the child SWF.

Move any code that accesses the stage from the `DocumentMain` constructor to an `ADDED_TO_STAGE` handler, like this:

```
public function DocumentMain()
{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
}

public function addedToStageHandler(ev:Event)
{
    trace(stage);
    //Code that was previously in the constructor
}
```